# tensorflow 2 evaluate inconsistent with sklearn accuracy_score

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn

I try to train a model to predict gender using Celeba dataset and tensorflow.
This is my model:

```
train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=train_split,
    directory=celeba.images_folder,
    x_col='id',
    y_col='Male',
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    classes=['1', '0']
)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    base_model,
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2),
    tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
])
base_learning_rate = 0.001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then I use the following to evaluate the model

```
test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=test_split,
    directory=celeba.images_folder,
    x_col='id',
    y_col='Male',
    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    classes=['1', '0']
)
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("cp-0004.ckpt")

# Re-evaluate the model
loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_data_gen, verbose=2)
```

which gives accuracy of 0.87

But when I use the following, I get 0.51 accuracy!

```
pred_test = model.predict(test_data_gen)

pred_df = pd.DataFrame(pred_test, columns=["Male", "Female"])
pred_df[pred_df > 0.5] = "1"
pred_df[pred_df < 0.5] = "0"

# test_split_raw = celeba.split('test', drop_zero=False)
confusion_matrix(test_split["Male"].astype(int).values, np.argmax(pred_df.values, 1))
```

Can anyone explain why the accuracy from the evaluate function is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check [test_image_generator.flow_from_dataframe](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). The default value of **shuffle** is set to **True**.

Your generator object therefore yields randomly from your test data.
Your model then predicts for those randomly generated images, but you compare to your ordered dataframe. If you want to compare to test_split["Male"] set **shuffle** to **False**. If you don't set **shuffle** to **False** you will always get ~0.5 accuracy (If your data is equally distributed)

Another hint: You should use the .evaluate() method if you have labeled data. Using .evaluate() also yields accuracy.
Use .predict() only for new, unlabeled data.